# Group AND sum fields in a Pivot Table

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2007, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in Excel 2007 which has 4 fields

- "In progress and still within SLA"

  - user 1: 10
  - user 2: 20
- "Completed
  outside SLA"

  - user 1: 33
  - user 2: 44
- "Completed within SLA"

  - user 1: 40
  - user 2: 45
- "In progress and outside SLA"

  - user 1: 5
  - user 2: 6

I want to group AND total the 2 "..within SLA" and the 2 "..outside SLA" fields so that I end up with data to build a chart from that represents

- "Within SLA"
- user 1: 50
- user 2: 65
- "Outside SLA"
- user 1: 38
- user 2: 50

I know you can group fields in a Pivot Table but I cannot see how I can then SUM the values together to have them represented as 1 category/axis in a chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- (collapse all categories)
- manually sort pivot table categories by drag/drop to have the "within's" and "outside's" close together
- select both "within" categories, then press right mouse key and select "Group"
- repeat with both "outside" categories

what you get is another group level which you can subtotal/sort/rename/whatever ... same as if you inserted such column in your detail data explicitely ... here in default layout the group sum is on top, you can change that via Pivot Table Tools / Design / Subtotals ...

[image]